# Using decorators with and without arguments simultaneously

Tags: python, decorator, python-2.6, python-decorators

I'm trying to measure the run-time of a decorated function like this:

```
import time

def timing_function(some_function):
    """Outputs the time a function takes to execute."""
    def wrapper():
        t1 = time.time()
        some_function()
        time.sleep(1)
        t2 = time.time()
        return "Time it took to run the function " + some_function.__name__ + " is " + str((t2-t1)) + "\n"
    return wrapper

def tags(tag_name):
    def tags_decorator(my_func):
        """Adds tags to a string."""
        def func_wrapper(name):
            return "<{0}>{1}</{0}>".format(tag_name, my_func(name))
        return func_wrapper
    return tags_decorator

@timing_function
@tags("p")
def get_text(name):
    return "Hello "+name
```

Then I try

```
print get_text("World")
```

but get

```
TypeError: wrapper() takes no arguments (1 given)
```

Interestingly, I added a piece of code to check what are the arguments I'm giving to wrapper():

```
def wrapper(*args):
    print "args", args
    # ...
```

It seems to get the argument "World", which should be actually passed to `get_text`.

Inverting the order of the decorators doesn't help. Is there anything I could do to implement in general decorators with and without arguments at the same time?

Of course I can merge both codes into a single wrapper, but that's not what I'm looking for...

I'm using python 2.6

Comment: It looks like the indentation on this code is shot - perhaps you could adjust it?

Comment: @PM2Ring: nope, because this is about passing arguments from decorator wrapper to decorated function. The `get_text()` function takes an argument, the wrapper produced by `timing_function` simply doesn't pass it on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to adjust your `wrapper()` function to accept an arbitrary number of arguments (positional and keyword), and *pass those on* to the wrapped function:

```
def timing_function(some_function):
    """Outputs the time a function takes to execute."""
    def wrapper(*args, **kw):
        t1 = time.time()
        some_function(*args, **kw)
        time.sleep(1)
        t2 = time.time()
        return "Time it took to run the function " + some_function.__name__ + " is " + str((t2-t1)) + "\n"
    return wrapper
```

The `*args` and `**kw` syntax in the `wrapper` function signature capture any positional and keyword arguments in a tuple and a dictionary, respectively. The very similar (related) syntax in a *call expression* takes a sequence or a dictionary and applies the contents of those as positional or keyword arguments to the object being called. This neatly passes on any number of arguments from the wrapper to the wrapped.

This wasn't an issue with your `tags` decorator, as its wrapper takes the exact same arguments as the wrapped function. That limits that decorator to functions that take exactly one argument (which is fine too).

Take into account that this decorator *ignores the return value* of the wrapped function; you are instead returning the timing results. You may want to still make the return value accessible (perhaps by returning a tuple of `(return_value, timing_info)`).

Demo:

```
>>> import time
>>> def timing_function(some_function):
...     """Outputs the time a function takes to execute."""
...     def wrapper(*args, **kw):
...         t1 = time.time()
...         some_function(*args, **kw)
...         time.sleep(1)
...         t2 = time.time()
...         return "Time it took to run the function " + some_function.__name__ + " is " + str((t2-t1)) + "\n"
...     return wrapper
... 
>>> def tags(tag_name):
...     def tags_decorator(my_func):
...         """Adds tags to a string."""
...         def func_wrapper(name):
...             return "<{0}>{1}</{0}>".format(tag_name, my_func(name))
...         return func_wrapper
...     return tags_decorator
... 
>>> @timing_function
... @tags("p")
... def get_text(name):
...     return "Hello "+name
... 
>>> get_text('World')
'Time it took to run the function func_wrapper is 1.00514888763\n'
```